# .net core with dotnet preview 2.0 cannot find files

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

My build definitions contains dotnet tasks. This is for a .Net Core 2.0 targeted build.

[image: image of build definition]

During build, the error I get is :

### [error]No files matched the search pattern.

I've tried so many iterations of picking the path to projects but nothing seems to be picking it up.

I know 2.* is in preview but still I'm sure ppl are using it for .net core 2.0 projects. Any help to how I might fix up my path string?

Comment: I know my path is correct, it's the same path used if I were to build as a regular Visual Studio Build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TFVC repo, you should specify the project path as below for .NET core task:

```
[local/map/path/]relative/path/to/csproj
```

Assume your TFVC repo folder structure as below:

```
TFVC Root (XPMoboleApp)
        |___API
             |___XP.API.DataObjects
                       |___XP.API.DataObjects
                                  |___XP.API.DataObjects.csproj
```

- In Get sources step, if you leave the **local map path empty**, you should specify the path to project(s) as:

  ```
  API/XP.API.DataObjects/XP.API.DataObjects/XP.API.DataObjects.csproj
  ```

  [image]
  [image]
- In Get sources step, if you **specified the local map path** (such as map `test` folder), you should set path to project(s) option as:

  ```
  test/API/XP.API.DataObjects/XP.API.DataObjects/XP.API.DataObjects.csproj
  ```

  [image]
  [image]

Comment: I know it's still in preview, but it is quite different from the previous methodology. Perhaps if it had the navigate to file? Just heard about the new Azure Project announcement! Neato.